# C# Xamarin.IOS / MonoTouch - Toolbar Disappears

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, toolbar, pushviewcontroller

I have a Xamarin.IOS/Monotouch project with 2 views - MainView and View2.

- My MainView window has a navigationController at the top, and a toolbar at the bottom.
- When I call PushViewController(View2,true); - I get pushed from MainView to my second view (View2).
- View2 also has a navigationController at the top, but it DOES NOT have a toolbar at the bottom - intentionally.
- When I click the "Back" button on View2 to push back to my MainView, the toolbar at the bottom of MainView has disappeared.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution in the end was to set "ToolBar.Hidden = false;" upon arriving in the view that I was pushing to.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Xamarin tutorial ([Multi-Screened Applications](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_mvc)). You can download the sample project, have a look at the code and try adding a UIToolBar to the HomeScreen. I did it and it works like a charm.

I'd also suggest the use of a storyboard: it really simplifies dealing with the navigation. A tutorial can be found [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_storyboards).

Hope this helps.